# notepad++ regex replace each occurence of a character only between two specific characters

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I want to replace each occurence of a character only between two specific characters within a text.

For example, here I want to replace each occurence of whitespaces or umlauts only between two quotation marks; also for multiple links:

```
1. Here is a <a href="#foö bar   foo bär">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
2. Here is a <a href="#foö bar   foo bär">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
3. Here is a <a href="#foö bar   foo bär">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
```

So I want to get the following text:

```
1. Here is a <a href="#fooe_bar_foo_baer">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
2. Here is a <a href="#fooe_bar_foo_baer">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
3. Here is a <a href="#fooe_bar_foo_baer">link</a> for foö bar and foo bär.
```

I was thinking about replacing something like this:

```
(?<="[^"]*)\(s+?)(?=[^"]*")|(?<="[^"]*)(ä)(?=[^"]*")|...
```

with:

```
(?1_)(?2ae)...
```

But quantifiers in a lookbehind doesn't work.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Edit: For more than only one link in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\s+)(?![^"]*(?:"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You use this with lookahead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/JLANJC/1

Comment: It will not work with multiple lines of this example. See https://regex101.com/r/JLANJC/2

Comment: It does also replace whitespaces outside of quotation marks for each line.

Comment: @MichaSch can you check again

Comment: Could you please help me again how I get this to work: https://regex101.com/r/JLANJC/6

Comment: This works: ([^A-Za-zÄÖÜäöüß_#"]+)(?![^"]*(?:"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

as 'search' you take:

```
"(.*)((ä)|(ö)|(ü)|(ß)|(\s))(.*)"
```

as 'replace' you take

```
"\1(?2(?3ae)(?4oe)(?5ue)(?6sz)(?7_))\8"
```

Edit:
added the missing umlauts

Comment: This will only replace the last occurence of matching character.